# Changing class in a UIView (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift

I would like to use a button to toggle the contents of a UIView.
I set up two classes, graphClass1 and graphClass2.  (The button is in the topView.)

When I click the button, I get the "my button" message from debugPrint, but I don't get the debugPrint messages from within the classes.  So, I added `setNeedsDisplay` but that did not help.

(This is a simplified version - there are actually a lot more classes - which is why I am trying to reuse the same view instead of just creating two separate views.)

1. how do I get the appropriate class to display in the view?
2. because graphClass1 creates additional subviews when I toggle back and forth, will the number of graphClass1's subviews just keep growing?  If so, how do I remove them when leaving?  (I know that `self.layer.sublayers = nil` or `textView.removeAll()`  would leave them until returning - if they even remove them at all.)
3. in the button toggle, rather than use a Bool to test which graph, I'd prefer something more intuitive like `if currentGraph ==  GraphClass1` but this gives me the error message: `Binary operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'UIView' and 'GraphClass1.Type'`.  How would do I fix this?

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var topView: UIView!    
    @IBOutlet var bottomView: UIView!    

    @IBOutlet var myButton: UIButton!    
    
    var graph1: Bool = true

    var currentView = UIView()
        
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()        
        bottomView = GraphClass1()
        setConstraints()
    }    

    @IBAction func myButton(_ sender: Any) {
        debugPrint("my button")
        if graph1 {
            currentView.removeFromSuperview()            
            currentView = GraphClass2()
            cv2.addSubview(currentView)
            graph1 = false
        }
        else {
            currentView.removeFromSuperview()
            currentView = GraphClass1()
            cv2.addSubview(currentView)
            graph1 = true
        }

        cv2.setNeedsDisplay()
    }
}

class GraphClass1: UIView {

    var textView = UITextView()

    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        super.draw(rect)                
        self.layer.sublayers = nil
        textView.removeAll()
        createTextView()
        debugPrint("inside GraphClass1")
    }

func createTextView() {
    textView = UITextView(frame: CGRect(x: 8, y: 8, width: 300, height: 100))
    textView.text = "Test, this is only a test"
    textView.textAlignment = .center
    textView.font = UIFont(name: "Courier", size: 16)
    textView.backgroundColor = .orange
    self.addSubview(textView)
    }
}

class GraphClass2: UIView {
    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        super.draw(rect)                
        debugPrint("inside GraphClass2")
    }
}
```

Comment: Since you don't init your views with a frame, I'm suspicious that their height/width might be zero.  Try using the View Debugger while the app is running to inspect your view hierarchy.

Comment: @PhillipMills: I am using stackoverflow.com/a/63365506/8635708 to do that - I just tried to simplify my questions as much as possible - but thank you for flagging that!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of changing the `UIView()` to a `GraphClass()`, you should add `GraphClass()` to `bottomView()` as a subview. To switch out `GraphClass1()`, you would remove it from `bottomView()` and set up `GraphClass2()` as the subview of `bottomView()`. Removing a view also removes all its subviews.

Comment: I tried the following: ````var currentView = UIView()```` then adding it as a subview like this: 
````currentView = GraphClass1()````
and 
````cv2.addSubview(currentView)````.
Can you give me some more explicit code?  (I'm pretty new to this.)

Answer (score 0):

First, create a bottomView in interface builder, just like the top view. It will be like a place holder. You will have;

```
      @IBOutlet var bottomView: UIView!
```

In viewDidLoad, you add the specific view as needed with

```
      bottomView.addSubView(myInstanceOfAGraphView.view)
      myInstanceOfAGraphView.didMove(toParent: bottomView)
```

I would create view controllers for each graph view and switch them as needed.

When you need to change, remove its view with;

```
      myInstanceOfAGraphView.view.removeFromSuperview()
```

Comment: this kind of makes sense to me (I'm still pretty new).  How do I create ````myInstanceOfAGraphView````?  Why create a view controller for each graph - wouldn't  the ````func draw(_ rect: CGRect)```` in each class already accomplish what I want when an instance of that class is created?

Comment: You can use one view controller and pass in a parameter to set the graph that you are going to draw. An instance of a view controller is just like any other class. eg - myInstanceOfAGraphViewController = myGraphViewController().

Comment: I've tried ````var currentView = UIView()```` then adding it as a subview like this: ````currentView = GraphClass1()```` and  ````cv2.addSubview(currentView)```` but it doesn't go into the ````GraphClass1()````.  Then I tried ````var currentView = GraphClass1()```` but can't change ````currentView```` to ````GraphClass2()````.  I'm still confused about using another view controller...

Comment: I really, really appreciate the help, but I am still floundering...

Comment: Have you updated your code to place bottomView in the view hierarchy? Currently you create a view and it is not added to your visible views anywhere. You cannot see anything drawn into it until it is added. As I wrote, I suggest that you add it in IB and make an outlet for it.

Comment: Yes, that was the first thing I did, using, as you suggested, ````@IBOutlet var bottomView: UIView!````.

Comment: I've updated the code in the original post and added a question.

Comment: add the 'didMove' call. See the sample code (now edited). Sorry,  I should have had that there from the start, I forgot we were in iOS. Put a button or something in the view controller and you should see it appear after this call.

Comment: I get the error message: ````Value of type 'UIView' has no member 'didMove'; did you mean 'willMove'?````.  If I add the ````.view```` in ````bottomView.addSubView(myInstanceOfAGraphView.view)```` I get the error message:  ````Value of type 'UIView' has no member 'view'````.

Comment: didMove is a method on UIViewController, not a UIView. and a UIView is already a view, so you don't add .view to it. myInstance... should be a UIViewController.

Comment: change graphClass1 and 2 to UIViewControllers like this;
 graphClass1 : UIViewController {....}